# Spring data cassandra reactive batch operation fails when ttl is set

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

Im using `reactiveCassandraTemplate.batchOps()` to insert multiple entities but

```
Codec not found for requested operation: [null <-> org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ExecutionProfileResolver$$Lambda$1967/0x0000020a03943b90
```

is thrown. one of these inserts has some ttl configuration with it and when that line gets removed things works correctly, but this ttl is needed for this insert. I don't know if this is a bug or I did something bad or doing it this way maybe is not appropriate for doing ttl. thanks in advance.

code of insertions:

```java
return reactiveCassandraTemplate
                .batchOps()
                .insert(doctorFromEvent(event, image))
                .insert(doctorBySpecialityFromEvent(event, image))
                .insert(locationFromEvent(event, image))
                .insert(new ProcessedEvent(event.id()), InsertOptions.builder().ttl(Duration.ofDays(30)))
                .execute()
                .handle((writeResult, sink) -> {
                    if (writeResult.wasApplied()) {
                        sink.next(Done.getInstance());
                        return;
                    }
                    sink.error(new RuntimeException("WriteResult.wasApplied was false, something bad happened"));
                });
```

Complete stack trace:

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: QueryForResultSet; CQL [INSERT INTO doctor (email,subjectid,address,adeli_number,bcrypted_password,date_of_birth,first_name,image,last_name,logo,mobile_number,rpps_number,specialization,theme_background_color,theme_button_color,theme_languages,theme_navbar_color,theme_subtitle,theme_text_color,theme_title) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);INSERT INTO doctor_by_speciality (specialization,fullname,email,subjectid,address,date_of_birth,image,mobile_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);INSERT INTO location (country,city,email,subjectid,longitude,latitude,address,full_name,image,mobile_number,specialization) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);INSERT INTO processed_event (id) VALUES (?);INSERT INTO insertoptionsbuilder (executionprofileresolver,ifnotexists,insertnulls,timeout,ttl) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);]; Codec not found for requested operation: [null <-> org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ExecutionProfileResolver$$Lambda$1967/0x0000020a03943b90]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ReactiveCassandraAccessor.translate(ReactiveCassandraAccessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ReactiveCqlTemplate.lambda$translateException$22(ReactiveCqlTemplate.java:719)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Mono.java:3783)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxHide.java:142)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:203)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:118)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:847)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:609)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:847)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:609)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:357)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoUsingWhen$MonoUsingWhenSubscriber.deferredComplete(MonoUsingWhen.java:268)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$CommitInner.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:527)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:384)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2072)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoHasElements$HasElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoHasElements.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2205)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2205)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:847)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:609)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage$MonoCompletionStageSubscription.apply(MonoCompletionStage.java:126)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage$MonoCompletionStageSubscription.apply(MonoCompletionStage.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:911)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.setFinalResult(CqlRequestHandler.java:324)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.access$1500(CqlRequestHandler.java:95)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler$NodeResponseCallback.onResponse(CqlRequestHandler.java:655)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.InFlightHandler.channelRead(InFlightHandler.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [null <-> org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ExecutionProfileResolver$$Lambda$1967/0x0000020a03943b90]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:639)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:558)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:92)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2276)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3973)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4957)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4963)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry.getCachedCodec(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:117)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.codecFor(CachingCodecRegistry.java:287)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.data.ValuesHelper.encodeToDefaultCqlMapping(ValuesHelper.java:136)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.Conversions.encode(Conversions.java:268)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.Conversions.toMessage(Conversions.java:232)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.sendRequest(CqlRequestHandler.java:279)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.onThrottleReady(CqlRequestHandler.java:195)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.throttling.PassThroughRequestThrottler.register(PassThroughRequestThrottler.java:52)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.<init>(CqlRequestHandler.java:172)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:44)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:29)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.AsyncCqlSession.executeAsync(AsyncCqlSession.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.session.DefaultBridgedReactiveSession.lambda$execute$0(DefaultBridgedReactiveSession.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$fromCompletionStage$0(Mono.java:554)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:45)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
[2023-10-19 23:14:34,066] [WARN] [akka.stream.scaladsl.RestartWithBackoffSource] [akka://ViteMeet@127.0.0.1:1600] [] [ViteMeet-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-32] - Restarting stream due to failure [1]: org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: QueryForResultSet; CQL [INSERT INTO doctor (email,subjectid,address,adeli_number,bcrypted_password,date_of_birth,first_name,image,last_name,logo,mobile_number,rpps_number,specialization,theme_background_color,theme_button_color,theme_languages,theme_navbar_color,theme_subtitle,theme_text_color,theme_title) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);INSERT INTO doctor_by_speciality (specialization,fullname,email,subjectid,address,date_of_birth,image,mobile_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);INSERT INTO location (country,city,email,subjectid,longitude,latitude,address,full_name,image,mobile_number,specialization) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);INSERT INTO processed_event (id) VALUES (?);INSERT INTO insertoptionsbuilder (executionprofileresolver,ifnotexists,insertnulls,timeout,ttl) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);]; Codec not found for requested operation: [null <-> org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ExecutionProfileResolver$$Lambda$1967/0x0000020a03943b90]
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: QueryForResultSet; CQL [INSERT INTO doctor (email,subjectid,address,adeli_number,bcrypted_password,date_of_birth,first_name,image,last_name,logo,mobile_number,rpps_number,specialization,theme_background_color,theme_button_color,theme_languages,theme_navbar_color,theme_subtitle,theme_text_color,theme_title) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);INSERT INTO doctor_by_speciality (specialization,fullname,email,subjectid,address,date_of_birth,image,mobile_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);INSERT INTO location (country,city,email,subjectid,longitude,latitude,address,full_name,image,mobile_number,specialization) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);INSERT INTO processed_event (id) VALUES (?);INSERT INTO insertoptionsbuilder (executionprofileresolver,ifnotexists,insertnulls,timeout,ttl) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);]; Codec not found for requested operation: [null <-> org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ExecutionProfileResolver$$Lambda$1967/0x0000020a03943b90]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ReactiveCassandraAccessor.translate(ReactiveCassandraAccessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ReactiveCqlTemplate.lambda$translateException$22(ReactiveCqlTemplate.java:719)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Mono.java:3783)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxHide.java:142)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:203)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:118)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:847)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:609)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:847)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:609)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:357)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoUsingWhen$MonoUsingWhenSubscriber.deferredComplete(MonoUsingWhen.java:268)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$CommitInner.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:527)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:384)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2072)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoHasElements$HasElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoHasElements.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2205)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2205)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:847)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:609)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage$MonoCompletionStageSubscription.apply(MonoCompletionStage.java:126)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage$MonoCompletionStageSubscription.apply(MonoCompletionStage.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:911)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.setFinalResult(CqlRequestHandler.java:324)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.access$1500(CqlRequestHandler.java:95)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler$NodeResponseCallback.onResponse(CqlRequestHandler.java:655)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.InFlightHandler.channelRead(InFlightHandler.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [null <-> org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ExecutionProfileResolver$$Lambda$1967/0x0000020a03943b90]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:639)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:558)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:92)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2276)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3973)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4957)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4963)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry.getCachedCodec(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:117)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.codecFor(CachingCodecRegistry.java:287)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.data.ValuesHelper.encodeToDefaultCqlMapping(ValuesHelper.java:136)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.Conversions.encode(Conversions.java:268)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.Conversions.toMessage(Conversions.java:232)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.sendRequest(CqlRequestHandler.java:279)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.onThrottleReady(CqlRequestHandler.java:195)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.throttling.PassThroughRequestThrottler.register(PassThroughRequestThrottler.java:52)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.<init>(CqlRequestHandler.java:172)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:44)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:29)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.AsyncCqlSession.executeAsync(AsyncCqlSession.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.session.DefaultBridgedReactiveSession.lambda$execute$0(DefaultBridgedReactiveSession.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$fromCompletionStage$0(Mono.java:554)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:45)
    ... 79 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me,

```java
.insert(new ProcessedEvent(event.id()), InsertOptions.builder().ttl(Duration.ofDays(30)).build()) // .build() was missing
```